# The Toggle Button Is Not Showing Up

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, togglebutton

I am trying to fix the toggle button but it is not working I can't tell if this is from me changing a few attributes on my own css file I have look everywhere but can't find an answer

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="room.css">

    <title>Museum of Candy</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar bg-dark"
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Navbar</span>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
       
      </div>
    
    
    </div>
  </nav>



   <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->

   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

---

```
body {
    background-color: pink
   
}

.navbar.bg-dark{
    
    opacity: 0.75;
}

.navbar-brand.mb-0.h1{

    
    

    color: white;
}
```

This is my html and CSS files I think the problem might be me changing the opacity of a CSS file but I am uncertain

Comment: Have you used your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being applied?

Comment: A quick look using browser dev tools shows that the toggler has background transparent and border transparent and there is no text in there so it doesn't show up. You an still click it and then it shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `navbar-dark` class to nav element

```
...
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-dark" >
...
```